# Add two sidebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I want to add two sidebars to my current website, but I'm confused how to do it. Do I add it outside the wrapper? I've tried to add it inside the wrapper, but it will stay at the top if I do so.

Thanks for all the help, I appreciate it

[fiddle/code click here](http://jsfiddle.net/U8x2n/)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I would suggest illustrating your problems on JS fiddle with simple DIVs with little content so we can better understand the layout you have in mind

Comment: @Shanks I uploaded a new JS fiddle now. http://jsfiddle.net/U8x2n/

Comment: @user that doesn't really help. Get rid of the Javascript and all the content... or well, everything really. Just use a few simple boxes to demonstrate your LAYOUT. The current fiddle is quite a mess.

Comment: for example: http://jsfiddle.net/U8x2n/1/

Answer (score 0):

To add columns left and right, we need to properly write markup example as:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
<div class="left-side"> </ div>
<div class="center"> </ div>
<div class="right-side"> </ div>
</ div>
```

where in the style sheet to specify the correct attributes

Comment: Of course, you do not correctly written markup html page, then why meta tag in your body, why do not understand, you need to invest your wrapper class first and then the center of the left column then right column

Comment: and your example you left column located outside the class wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Add the css `float:left` to your sidebars and your main content, along with a width. The float will make them line up next to each other.

You might also want to look into a CSS framework like [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which provides many pre-made classes for layout, as well as [example templates](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). Using Bootstrap, your html would be similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div role="aside" id="sidebar1" class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div role="main" id="main" class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div role="aside" id="sidebar2" class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added bootstrap to my webserver. Where in the CSS and HTML do I put this code? Do I need to change something out or?

Comment: These are the containers for your content and should be added to your html. Put your main content within the middle div with the id "main". Put your sidebar content in the other two divs; sidebar1 will be on the left.